# Writing a SUM statement within a column group that has multiple columns

Tags: reporting-services

Please see image for my questions  Thanks

[Question and example typed in word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XOQb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the value of the field `TotalCamp` minus the two other fields (OT, HRRG). So your expression for the **Salary** should look like this:

```
=Fields!TotalCamp.Value - (Fields!OTAmount.Value + Fields! HRRGAmount.Value)
```

If you have your tablix grouped you need to add the scope as well:

```
=(Fields!TotalCamp.Value, "YourGroupName") - ((Fields!OTAmount.Value, "YourGroupName") + (Fields!HRRGAmount.Value, "YourGroupName"))
```